# URLRewrite Rule NetCore2.0 Remove WWW

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Goal: Try to remove www. from url (eg. http://www.myurl.com/r/reddit/other to http://myurl.com/r/reddit/other)

What is broken? url rewrite not working to redirect it to the non www site?

What Happens? Nothing it doesn't work it compiles fine but the www url
hangs until connection time out and doesn't redirect as the code intends to do

This is my code. I am not sure what is happening but the specs for this application:

Net Core 2.0 
with Net core 2.0.9 runtime

Rule

```
 public class WWWRule : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        if (request.Host.Value.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            var newhost = request.Host.Value.Substring(4);
            string redirectUrl = $"{request.Scheme}://{newhost}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = redirectUrl;
            response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
        }
    }

}
```

Startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions().Add(new WWWRule());
        app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
  }
```

See nuget lib
[image]

Comment: Questions: what doesn't work? Have you tried debugging? Why are you trying to do this in ASP.NET Core? This type of task is much more suited to the server hosting the app

Comment: Perhaps I can do it on the hosting server but the question is about why url reqrite while an option for net core is not working for me with my code

Comment: And my question was what exactly doesn't work. You didn't provide any details. Does it fail to compile? Does it throw an exception? What exactly happens?

Comment: Sorry I will re-edit. Nothing it doesn't work it compiles fine but the www url hangs until connection time out and doesn't redirect as the code intends to do.

Comment: Create a middleware to do that instead of using UseRewriter/IRule. The Rewrite module is here to edit the current request settings without asking the client to redirect

Comment: @Kalten do you mean create another netcore project with in the same server and put my code there instead ? having it bind to the www version for site?

Comment: No, I sugget [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#write-middleware). But I tried your sample and it work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Remember to actually register the subdomain in DNS records. 
(CNAME, www, yourServerName)